# does file_watch supports windows?

Tags: ruby, eventmachine

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'eventmachine'
module Handler
  def file_modified
    puts "#{path} file modified\n Modified contents:#{get_modified_contents}"
  end
end

def get_modified_contents
  file1 = File.open("#{File.join(Dir.pwd,'test.txt')}",'r+')
  file2_r = File.open("#{File.join(Dir.pwd,'track.txt')}",'r')
  prev_pos = file2_r.read.to_i
  curr_pos = file1.size
  file1.seek(prev_pos)
  modified_contents = file1.read
  file2_w =File.open('track.txt','w')
  file2_w.write(curr_pos)
  modified_contents
end

EventMachine.kqueue = true if EventMachine.kqueue?
EventMachine.run {
  EventMachine.watch_file("#{File.join(Dir.pwd,'test.txt')}",Handler)
}"
```

I am trying to run above program and getting following error. please suggest solution. I have installed event machine.

```
Installer/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-          1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1285:in `watch_filename': no file watching support on     this system (EventMachine::Unsupported)
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-    1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:1285:in `watch_file'   from     C:/Users/PK64/Documents/Aptana Studio 3         Workspace/FileIO/eventmachine_prac.rb:31:in `block in <main>'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-    1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-    1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/eventmachine-1.0.7/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    from C:/Users/PK64/Documents/Aptana Studio 3     Workspace/FileIO/eventmachine_prac.rb:30:in `<main>'
```

Comment: It should work. From [their website](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine): "EventMachine supports Ruby >= 1.8.7 and <= 2.2 REE, JRuby and works well on Windows as well as many operating systems from the Unix family (Linux, Mac OS X, BSD flavors)."